# Django + Pythonanywhere: How to disable Debug Mode

Tags: django, pythonanywhere

I am using Django and PythonAnywhere, and I want to make the `DEBUG` to **False**. But when I set it to **False** and make `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']`, it works fine. But the problem is the media (or the images) is not displaying. Anyone encounter this and know how to resolve it?

Comment: do you have MEDIA_URL to MEDIA_ROOT set correctly ?

Comment: yes I have it set correctly when DEBUG=True on my settings.py it works fine in PythonAnywhere. But when I try to make the DEBUG=False and make Allowed_host=['*']. The images is diplaying on my Pythonanywhere site

Comment: you have to set media file mapping `PythonAnywhere dashboard`

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: In Dashboard do you see any Meida File section ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I Figured it out, thanks for the hint Mr. Raja Simon.

In my PythonAnywhere Dashboard on Web Tab. I set something like this..

URL             /media/

Directory   /home//media_cdn

*media_cdn is where my images located.

Comment: PythonAnywhere dev here -- sounds like you found the right solution.  A bit of explanation about why you needed to do that: when Django is in debug mode, it will serve up your static files for you.  This is convenient when you're developing, but *very* inefficient for live sites, because Django serves the static files using slow Python code.  So when you switch off debug mode, it stops serving them.  The static files config in PythonAnywhere enables our own servers to handle them so that they can take over from Django.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it very well, I'm kinda new in Django and PythonAnywhere.